# Req body Returns Undefined and Empty Object Express console, But it prints fine in Postman

Tags: node.js, express

Request body is always returning {} undefined when I send request through the HTML reg-page. But when I try to log request through API(POSTMAN) it returns success. I tried bodyParser method other way also but yet it Didn't work.

When I log req through HTML-REGISTRATION PAGE

```
    {}
POST /api/register 200 4.361 ms - 15
```

When I log req through to the API through POSTMAN (Success)

```
    { name: 'Sabfgitvdsh', email: 'sa@vdsgg.c', password: 'csacngfsa' }
POST /api/register 200 1.286 ms - 15
```

**Server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path =require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const connectDB = require('./server/database/connection');

const app=express();


app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));


dotenv.config({path:'config.env'});

const PORT=process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Morgan Module--log request
app.use(morgan('dev')); 


// Database coonection
connectDB();


// load assets
app.use('/css', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/css")));
app.use('/img', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/img")));
app.use('/js', express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "assets/js")));
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')))


app.post('/api/register', async (req, res)=>{


   
     
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json({status: 'ok'})
   
})




app.listen(PORT, ()=> {console.log('Server is running on', PORT)})
```

**SCRIPT.JS**

```
const registerButton = document.getElementById("register");
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login");
const container = document.getElementById("container");

registerButton.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
   container.classList.add("right-panel-active");
});

loginButton.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
   container.classList.remove("right-panel-active");
});


const form = document.getElementById('reg-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', registerUser);

async function registerUser(event){
   event.preventDefault()
   const username = document.getElementById('username').value
   const email = document.getElementById('userEmail').value
   const password = document.getElementById('password').value

   const result = await fetch('/api/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      header: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
         username, email, password
      })
   }).then((res)=> res.json())

   console.log(result)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use headers in your fetch, not header

```
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pass `headers` instead of `header` in the fetch function like below. it should work.

```
const result = await fetch('/api/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
         username, email, password
      })
   }).then((res)=> res.json())
```